# How to create round robin lead assignment for certain lead status value and lead source?

Tags: trigger, leads, automation, process-automation, process-automation-settings

I have done the setup listed here (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004000&type=1) for round robin lead assignment, but 'd like to do a lead assignment based on two criteria: the lead's status (Appointment Set) and it's sub source- a custom field (Facebook).

My formula looks like this :

```
AND(
    TEXT(Status) = "Appt. Set",
    TEXT(Lead_Sub_Source__c) = "Facebook"), 
    MOD(VALUE(Lead_Number__c) ,2) + 1, 
    0
)
```

I'm planning on rotating leads with this specific status and sub source between just two owners.

I keep getting an error that I have an extra ',' or '(' and I've tried modifying the formula with &&, AND etc., but just can't make it work.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Based on the details in the comments and the [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004000&type=1), you are getting this wrong. You will need to add the additional condition in the assignment rule and not while creating the `Lead_Number__c` field.So your assignment rule would look like something as:

```
(Lead: Status EQUALS Appt. Set) AND (Lead: Lead_Sub_Source__c EQUALS Facebook) AND (Lead_Number__c EQUALS 1)
```

The formula to compute the `Lead_Number__c` should align to what it is mentioned in the knowledge article.

---

You seem to have an extra parenthesis on this line:

```
TEXT(Lead_Sub_Source__c) = "Facebook"),
```

Your formula should look like as below. Notice the `)` has been removed after the text `"Facebook"` and the possibly you are trying to validate the `MOD` value, so that has been adjusted to make sure the formula is syntactically correct. You should review the exact implementation based on your use case.

```
AND(
    TEXT(Status) = "Appt. Set",
    TEXT(Lead_Sub_Source__c) = "Facebook", 
    (MOD(VALUE(Lead_Number__c) ,2) + 1) = 0
)
```

Comment: I get an error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'AND()'. Expected Boolean, received Number

Comment: I had not validated it. But seems you are trying to verify the result of `MOD` to `0`, so you will need to adjust it accordingly. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Number).

Comment: That could be possibly because your formula return type is of type `Number`. Because you are using `AND` here, the formula has to have a return type as `Checkbox`.

Comment: The formula type needs to be a number since the idea is to generate a Round Robin ID- based on which the lead assignment rule is supposed to work. However, I need to generate the ID number only for leads that meet the two criteria ( status and sub source). I know it sounds confusing, but it's more clearly stated in the link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004000&type=1

Comment: You are getting that a bit incorrectly here. You will need to have the condition for `Status` and `Lead_Sub_Source__c` on the assignment rule along with the `Lead_Number__c` field. This formula as currently written will always return a `Boolean`.

Comment: Does it mean I need to use && instead of AND?

Comment: You don't need to use this in the formula you are creating. I would imagine you are still creating the `Lead_Number__c` field. Once you have created this just as mentioned in the article, you will then need to configure Lead Assignment Rule as described there. During that, you will need to include your custom fields. I will recommend to also take a look at some of the concepts around Lead Assignment Rules.

Comment: 1. The links above are outdated. 2. I believe Lead_Number__c is an auto-increment field. In that case, this formula would be incorrect. Imagine the scenario where every 3rd lead meets the "Facebook" criteria, it would always be assigned to the same person.